# How to access strings in saved array structure from UITableView

Tags: arrays, swift, class, core-data, struct

I have structure that consists of strings and an array of exercises. Users input their exercises and these values are saved to the device using core data. The values are shown in a UITableview. I have added a button to the UITableview so that the details that the user has inputted can be edited. My problem is I don't know how to access the specific text that the user has entered to enable them to edit it.

My array:

```
var contacts = [Contact]()
```

Structure:

```
//Structure
struct Contact {
var id:String = "Contact - \(UUID())"
var fullname: String
var exercises : [Exercise]
}
```

My Exercise class

```
class Exercise : NSObject , NSSecureCoding{
static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

var excerciseName: String
var excerciseReps: String
var excerciseSets: String
var excerciseWeights: String

init(Name : String, Reps : String, Sets : String, Weights : String) {
    excerciseName = Name
    excerciseReps = Reps
    excerciseSets = Sets
    excerciseWeights = Weights
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(excerciseName, forKey: "excerciseName")
    aCoder.encode(excerciseReps, forKey: "excerciseReps")
    aCoder.encode(excerciseSets, forKey: "excerciseSets")
    aCoder.encode(excerciseWeights, forKey: "excerciseWeights")
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let excerciseName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseName") as! String
    let excerciseReps = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseReps") as! String
    let excerciseSets = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseSets") as! String
    let excerciseWeights = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseWeights") as! String

    self.init(Name: excerciseName, Reps: excerciseReps, Sets: excerciseSets, Weights: excerciseWeights)

   }
  }
```

The code I am using to try and access the specific exercise that the user has entered is

```
print(self.contacts[indexPath.section].exercises)
```

However this will print the below value seen in the image and not the actual text that the user has entered. how to i access the actual text that the user has entered?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get the number part of the id, just remove the 'Contact - ' part on the line I commented on

```
//Structure
struct Contact {
var id:String = "Contact - \(UUID())"  //this line
var fullname: String
var exercises : [Exercise]
}
```